# Using a map within a map in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{normalizedData.map(obj => 
    <div key={obj.display_date_numberic}>
        <div>{obj.display_date_numberic}</div>
    </div>

    {!isEmpty(obj.applicants) && obj.map(obj2 => 
        <div className="events">{obj2.person.name}</div>
    )}
)}
```

I'm getting an error on the following line:

```
{!isEmpty(obj.applicants) && obj.map(obj2 =>
```

Why can't I use the map function inside another map? `normalizedData` has an array of objects and each `obj` has another array of objects.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You can't use `map` on object - `map` is an array method.

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz array of object is array

Comment: @Aron unexpected token

Comment: Well there you go. You can't map on an object in vanilla JS. If you do want to though you can always use [`lodash/map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map)

Comment: You are returning multiple elements. You should wrap everything in a div or something convenient.

Comment: And also inside a `.map` you can only return one element, so you need to wrap the bit starting with `{!isEmpty ...` in a single containing div.

Comment: @GialaJefferson  yes but your second `map` is used on object - at least `obj.map` suggests so.

Answer (score 20):

You can do a map within a map as follows:

e.g. given data of

```
outerArray: [
  { id: '1st', name: 'First', innerArray: [ 'this', 'that' ]},
  { id: '2nd', name: 'Second', innerArray: [ 'some', 'what' ]},
]
```

you can use JSX:

```
{outerArray.map(outerElement => (
  <>
    <div>Outer: {outerElement.name}</div>
    <ul>
      {outerElement.innerArray.map(innerElement => (
        <li key={innerElement}>
          {innerElement}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </>
))}
```

which renders:

```
<div>Outer: First</div>
<ul>
  <li>this</li>
  <li>that</li>
</ul>
<div>Outer: Second</div>
<ul>
  <li>some</li>
  <li>what</li>
</ul>
```

note the use of key= inside the map to ensure React has a unique reference for the element from each loop iteration.  If you don't it will warn you!

Comment: you changed the structure of their array. They had a div within the Outer Array and then a Div within the Inner.
you have rendered this flat, all within the inner.
So I do not think you have answered the question.

Comment: @TheArchitecta you are right, but then the OP's code was so riddled with issues I didn't even bother trying to reuse it.  So my answer addresses the fundamental question of how to use a map within a map. But I'll update my answer to provide a (corrected) version of the OP code, in case it helps you/others

Answer (score 3):

Reason is, you are trying to `render` more than one element, and we can't do that, we can return only one element. So wrap all the logic and elements inside one `div` like this:

```
{normalizedData.map(obj => 
    <div key={obj.display_date_numberic}>
        <div>{obj.display_date_numberic}</div>

        {Array.isArray(obj.applicants) && obj.applicants.map(obj2 => 
           <div className="events">{obj2.person.name}</div>
        )}
    </div>
)}
```

Assuming `obj.applicants` is an `array`, use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray?v=control) to check whether any value is a proper array or not

**Note:** We can use `map` only on `array` not on any `object`, so if obj is an object and use `Object.keys(obj)` to get an `array` of all the keys then use `map` on that.

Comment: Please note that `map` can't be used on object since it's array method. And in above example `obj` seems to be an object...

Comment: actually there's no problem with my map, now I'm getting isEmpty is not defined ouch.

Comment: @GialaJefferson check the updated answer, it will work, let me know if you face any issue in that :)

Comment: I do isEmpty is because applicants might me zero length.

Comment: no required, because Array.isArray([]) will return true, then [].map will no do anything since length is zero that check you  can skip. it will work in that condition also.

Answer (score 3):

The  evident error that you hace in your code is that , you should be mapping on `obj.applicants` in the inner map and not `obj` and return a single element from the outer map

Also if obj.applicants is an array, no need to use `isEmpty`

```
{normalizedData.map(obj => 
    <div>
    <div key={obj.display_date_numberic}>
        <div>{obj.display_date_numberic}</div>
    </div>

    { obj.applicants.map(obj2 => 
        <div className="events">{obj2.person.name}</div>
    )}
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just advice, you can use `for` instead of `map`